# exposed form in block in Drupal

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views

i am working on a project by Drupal.

i created a view with exposed filters on it.the display type for it is page and i set 'exposed form in block' option of it to yes to put this page in a block on the right.

it is shown on right side on my site,but no title for it is shown.i have set its title but no changes.its title appears on the result page only.

any help?? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a title in Administration > Site Building > Blocks. Another way is to make a title in the "header" section of the view.